# DataGrid scrolling performance is poor

Tags: wpf, performance, scroll, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which has about 100 rows.
Each row has two `ComboBox`es.
In my opinion, the scrolling is not smooth and not fast enough. 
I would like to have an UI experience like I have in Excel: if you scroll there, the scrolling happens immediately without **any** delay.

In my `DataGrid` I have the following:

- All the columns have fixed width.
- `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"`
- `EnableColumnVirtualization="False"`
- `ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"` (I'm not a fan of this one)
- The binding `ItemsSource` is `IsAsync=True`

The above statements help but it's still not good enough.

I already tried to put the row virtualizing to false. Of course this solves the scrolling problem, but then the loading time takes very long.

Is there a way to set the row virtualizing to true and then the `DataGrid` rows start loading into memory in the background?

Or is there another option that I'm not considering?

Will the problem be completely solved by not using the `ComboBox`es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by all the comboboxes. I removed all of them and everything is ok now.